# Using ACF to display data on all pages

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I have installed [Advanced Custom Fielts](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), and I have created custom fields such as email, phone etc. I put those in my footer.php, and the data is displayed only on the homepage.
Can I use ACF to create global variables?
My rule for that custom field is `'If Post Type is equal to post';`

I get that data in footer.php like this

```
$phone_number = get_field('phone_number');
```

and Im displaying it like

```
<?php echo $phone_number; ?>
```

So basically when Im on my homepage, it is displayed correctly, when I go to other page(which has that same footer), data is not displayed.
What can I do to display it on all pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Need to use [ACF Options Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-option-pages/) plugin as well.

***This Plugin has been deleted from the repository. Now you can use the function without the plugin.***

The options page feature provides a set of functions to add extra admin pages and all data saved on an options page is **global**.

Sea the plugin [overview](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/)

After installing plugin you have to add the following to your `functions.php`

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    
    acf_add_options_page();
    
}
```

and the "*Options*" label will be visible in your admin area.

then you just need to create acf fields with the rule like `'If Options Page is equal to Options'`

Finally to display the field:

```
echo get_field('phone_number', 'option');
```

Comment: Thats wrong. You do not need any plugin for the acf options.

Comment: What? what's wrong?

Comment: He talk about global options and for global option you NEED plugin

Comment: Theres no need for that plugin. With acf_add_options_page you create the page with get_field('xyz', 'option') you get the option.

Comment: The options page feature provides a set of functions to add extra admin pages to edit ACF fields! Each admin page can be fully customized (see code examples below), and sub admin pages can be created too!

All data saved on an options page is global. This means it is not attached to any particular post or page, but is saved in the wp_options table. This allows the data to be displayed on any page throughout the website (good for header and footer data)!

Comment: my answer isn't wrong, the plugin provides more easy way to have global options, without coding and setting options manually

Comment: Huh ... probably your right. We are using ACF Pro forever and there is no need for that. Maybe in the free versions this plugin/addon is necessary. I thought that as of ACF v5.0 these functionalities are also in the free plugin. My bad ;)

Comment: No problem, just vote up )))

Comment: Just tried that but its actually not possible until the answer is edited :/

Comment: I don't understand? what should I do?

Comment: Edit just anything. Then my vote is unlocked. Are you sure about that plugin? ... seems odd to me that this should be the official way of doing this in the free plugin but elliot isn't a contributer for that.

Comment: ok I have just edited. I am working with ACF and ACF PRO already for 4 years. ACF PRO has "options page" plugin in it as well as "reapeter" plugin, but free version doesn't support the global options page without addon

Comment: I was able to make it work. Followed your steps, but instead of echo get_field('phone_number', 'option'); , I used get_field('phone_number', '200');, where 200 is ID of that Options Page.

Comment: that will also work ))

Answer (score 6):

As other users mention to create global options you need to have [ACF Options Page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/) add-on or [ACF PRO](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/). This will give you possibility to create nice options page and retrive your field in standard way:

```
$phone_number = get_field( 'phone_number', 'option' );
```

However there is a trick you can use to retrive your fields on every page.

If your options are working only on homepage I'm assuming you created custom fields on your homepage administration page. To retrive this fields on other pages pass your homepage ID as second argument.

```
$homepage_id = get_option('page_on_front');

$phone_number = get_field( 'phone_number', $homepage_id );
```

Comment: I will vote up your answer due to my similar answer got voted down unfairly

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're setting the field value as a post_meta value.

To achieve what you're trying to achieve, you need to create an options page. See: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/

That will allow you to display data globally.